# Adding jQuery code in Joomla

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I need to add this code to Joomla please

```
$(".item-204").append('<ul class="nav-child unstyled small"><li class="item-205"><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=9" >رؤيتنا</a></li>');
```

what is the best way?

Comment: Find file of target page and add your code into it.

Comment: @Mohammad It is in main page for offcanvas menu but how can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use [Regular Labs ReReplacer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/rereplacer) which could be set up to replace the `.item-204` code with `.item-204` plus any additional code you require. I am assuming `.item-204` is unique on the page.

The advantage of using this extension is that you don't have to find or update the core code. Updating core code is often considered bad practice as any future template or extension updates can undo your changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's really just about adding this code to every page? Instead of adding another plugin so your site you can put your code in a script tag located in your templates main php file. This file is named `index.php` and is located here: `/templates/[your template name]/index.php`

If you want to do it even better, place this code in the templates JS file. Some of them have a file like `/templates/[your template name]/js/custom.js`which is a good place to add custom JS to.